ESP32 WiFi Mesh networking problem - Cant connect to HTTPS server by IP address from MESH_NODES
I have 3 ESP32-S3 dev kits. They are all running the same software.
I have a WIFI Mesh network and MQTT and OTA implemented.
I have an self organised WIFI mesh network a node acting as my MESH_ROOT positioned right next to my WIFI AP, and 2 MESH_NODEs close enough to get RSSI figures of around -60dB
I can run MQTT on all the nodes with the furthest running through the Mesh network to my Access Point / Modem Router and on to a HIVEMQ broker.  This works flawlessly but it connects using the URI: "mqtts://d72b.......244.s1.eu.hivemq.cloud:8883"
But my OTA which uses an HTTPS to a server on my laptop, which for now I am triggering manually, works reliable on the MESH_ROOT node only.
On the MESH_NODEs it can't connect to my HTTPS server using a local LAN static IP address 192.168.1.2:8070
On the Mesh Node I get:
W (00:14:10.830) esp-tls: Failed to open new connection in specified timeout
E (00:14:10.832) transport_base: Failed to open a new connection
E (00:14:10.849) HTTP_CLIENT: Connection failed, sock < 0
E (00:14:10.850) esp_https_ota: ESP HTTP client perform failed: 28674
E (00:14:10.852) aOTA: ESP HTTPS OTA Begin failed
E (00:14:10.864) esp_https_ota: esp_https_ota_get_img_desc: Invalid argument
E (00:14:10.865) aOTA: esp_https_ota_read_img_desc failed
I (730801) mesh: 5170<active>parent layer:1(node), channel:7, rssi:-79, assoc:1(cnx rssi threshold:-120)my_assoc:0
I (732301) mesh: 5969<scan>parent layer:1, rssi:-79, assoc:1(cnx rssi threshold:-120)
I (732311) mesh: [SCAN][ch:7]AP:2, other(ID:0, RD:0), MAP:2, idle:0, candidate:2, root:2, topMAP:0[c:2,i:2][00:17:13:20:bd:74]<weak>
I (732321) mesh: 7391[weak]try rssi_threshold:-120, backoff times:0, max:5<-78,-82,-85>
I (732331) mesh: 710[monitor]new parent:48:ca:43:9b:53:d9<layer:1, rssi:-62, assoc:0>current parent:30:30:f9:33:49:bd<layer:1, rssi:-79, assoc:1>max cnx:6
I (732341) mesh: 1026[monitor]candidate:ESPM_9B53D8, rssi:-62, 48:ca:43:9b:53:d9[layer:1]

At the same time on the MESH_ROOT I get:
E (00:03:24.279) mesh_netif: Send with err code 16392 ESP_ERR_MESH_ARGUMENT
E (00:03:24.580) mesh_netif: Send with err code 16392 ESP_ERR_MESH_ARGUMENT
E (00:03:25.182) mesh_netif: Send with err code 16392 ESP_ERR_MESH_ARGUMENT
E (00:03:26.385) mesh_netif: Send with err code 16392 ESP_ERR_MESH_ARGUMENT
E (00:03:28.783) mesh_netif: Send with err code 16392 ESP_ERR_MESH_ARGUMENT
E (00:03:33.588) mesh_netif: Send with err code 16392 ESP_ERR_MESH_ARGUMENT
E (00:03:39.365) mesh_netif: Send with err code 16392 ESP_ERR_MESH_ARGUMENT
E (00:03:39.396) mesh_netif: Send with err code 16392 ESP_ERR_MESH_ARGUMENT
E (00:03:39.698) mesh_netif: Send with err code 16392 ESP_ERR_MESH_ARGUMENT
E (00:03:40.297) mesh_netif: Send with err code 16392 ESP_ERR_MESH_ARGUMENT

I think I am missing something in my understanding?

I have also discovered if I publish more than 2 MQTT messages at a time, on a MESH_NODE it disconnects from the broker.  I have added throttling with a "message in flight" counter but this is not necessary on the MESH_ROOT. This is really not my code, its just a merge of the IDF example projects: ip_internal_network and advanced_https_ota.  Has anyone managed to get OTA from remote https server working through the ESP32 WIFI mesh?
